# Automation Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i am struggling to understand why i receive an automation error when i try to run the below code:

```
Sub macro

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook

filter = "files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim j As Integer

j = 2
While sourceSheet.Cells(j, 1) <> ""
```

The error appears once i create the loop, it appears regardless if i continue the body of the loop or not. I cannot understand why as i have already run a similar macro with such a loop without errors.

Specifically the error is:

> Run time error '-2147221080 (800401a8): Automation error

Comment: Code runs successfully for me.  Is this the only code being run?  Is there something weird about the workbook selected?  Is there something weird about the workbook's first worksheet's cell A2?

Comment: on what line does it break?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code in that subroutine. On what line does it break? Declare j as long just to be sure. Does it go through the loop once at all or break straight away? You don't have any error handling; do you know your open workbook & set sheet is working correctly?

Comment: what does this mean? `once i create the loop`

Comment: fyi: when talking about programming, `similar macro` means `different macro`

Comment: This is the only code that is being run. Still gives me that error, that is why i have not posted the rest of the code. The excel sheet i am loading is fine, i have tried with several ad still gives me the error. If i put ' in from of my loop, the code works but once i try to create the Loop this error appears. I have tried to declare j as Long instead of integer, and now it gives me Run time error 1004... cannot understand why all this is not working...

Comment: You have said several times that the error occurs when you **create** the loop. Is that really true or does it occur **after** you create the loop when you try to run the code?  And, if it occurs when running, does it occur when it reaches the `While sourceSheet.Cells(j, 1) <> ""` statement for the first time, or does it occur when it reaches it for about the 1 millionth time, or something in between, or does it occur on some other completely unrelated line?

Comment: Hi YowE3K. The erroro occurs when it reaches this line: While sourceSheet.Cells(j, 1) <> "" . Regardless if i write soemthing after that or i leave it as the last line of the code, the error occurs.

Comment: If that was the last line of your code you should get syntax errors, so it shouldn't even attempt to run anything, so it should never reach that line.